# Not seeing all values of list when I create a dataframe from list

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter, vertica-python

I am using `VerticaPy` - https://www.vertica.com/python/

I have created two `vDataFrame` using `train.csv` and `test.csv` of `kaggle`'s Titanic problem. the `vDataFrames` are created correctly

```
train_vdf = read_csv("train.csv")
train_vdf
```

[image]

```
test_vdf = read_csv("test.csv")
test_vdf
```

[image]

I then create a combined list and create a `pandas` `dataframe` from it

```
combine = [train_vdf, test_vdf] #gives a list
combine_pdf = pd.DataFrame(combine)
combine_pdf
```

But the output doesn't show the combined data from the two `vDataFrames`s

[image]

Why don't I see the combined data in a table?

Comment: I am not an expert, but may be pandas concat can do the trick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change to `concat`

```
combine_pdf = pd.concat(combine)
```

Comment: can you explain why I saw the output which I saw in my original problem. Is it that `combine` is a list of `vDataFrames` which means it contains two objects each of which contain the columns of `vDataFrame`. Thus the `Pandas` `DataFrame` shows the column definitions of the `vDataFrames`

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to create a dataframe with a combination of the columns in both input dataframes and row count equal to the sum of the row counts for each input, you can do this:

```py
import pandas as pd
train_vdf = pd.DataFrame({
    'PassengerId' : [1,2],
    'Survived' : [0,1],
    'Pclass' : [3,1],
    'Name' : ['Braund, Mr. Owen Harris', 'Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley'],
    'Sex' : ['male', 'female'],
    'Age' : [22.0, 38.0]
})
test_vdf = pd.DataFrame({
    'PassengerId' : [895,896],
    'Pclass' : [3,3],
    'Name' : ['Wirz, Mr. Albert', 'Hirvonen, Mrs. Alexander'],
    'Sex' : ['male', 'female'],
    'Age' : [27.0, 22.0],
    'SibSp' : [0, 1]
})
df = pd.concat([train_vdf, test_vdf], ignore_index=True)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   PassengerId  Survived  Pclass                        Name     Sex   Age  SibSp
0            1       0.0       3     Braund, Mr. Owen Harris    male  22.0    NaN
1            2       1.0       1  Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley  female  38.0    NaN
2          895       NaN       3            Wirz, Mr. Albert    male  27.0    0.0
3          896       NaN       3    Hirvonen, Mrs. Alexander  female  22.0    1.0
```